# PHP OOP Fetch array from Database with mysql

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, oop

Hi guys I have the following code :

```
$this->db->setQuery("SELECT id,grad FROM login WHERE Email='$Email' AND Parola='$Parola' LIMIT 1");
//setQuery Is setting the Query 
if($this->db->NumRows() > 0) {
//Checking if Number of Rows is greater than 0 

    if(session_id() == ''){
         session_start();
    }

    $this->Email = $Email;

    while($row = mysql_fetch_array($this->db->GetResource())){
        //Fetching from the database the "Id" And "Grad"
        $this->Id = $row[0];
        $this->Grad = $row[1];
    }
    echo $this->Id . "<br />";
    echo $this->Grad . "<br / >";
}
```

Although is working as I planned, I am not satisfied with the code, I want to get the information for "Id" and "Grad" from the "db" like this.

```
$this->Id = $this->db->getInfo();
$this->Grad = $this->db->getInfo();
```

Well here I get stuck when trying to echo "Id" and "Grad" I get his Notice

> Notice: Array to string conversion in
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\poo\classes\MVC\userlogin.php on line 39 Array

Code for getInfo() :

```
//$this->Resource is the mysql_query of the setQuery
$this->Rows = array();

if ($this->Resource) {

    while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($this->Resource)) {

        $this->Rows[] = $row;

    }

}
return $this->Rows;
```

I want to mention that I am a beginner in PHP and OOP.
Code to all function used http://tny.cz/4c5596fc

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So it looks like the getInfo() would get the 1st value of the 1st row, then when called the second time get the 2nd value of the first row. What if it's called a third time?

One thing you could do, since you are only fetching 1 row, is to just return mysql_fetch_assoc($this->Resource) in your getInfo() without the while loop. This will just give you the first row as an associative array and you could do:

```
$row = $this->db->getInfo();
$this->Id = $row['id'];
$this->Grad = $row['grad'];
```

I should also mention here that the mysql_ functions are deprecated and the code is prone to mysql injection attacks if the user supplies $Email or $Parola. Take a look into PDO and prepared statements to prevent this.
If you really prefer the format you have, you could do it like this in your getInfo():

```
if (!$this->Row) {
    if ($this->Resource) {
        $this->Row = mysql_fetch_array($this->Resource);
    }
}
return array_shift($this->Row);
```

Comment: i am aware of SQL Injection being possible , i will check PDO later as i get more knowledge on PHP.

Answer (score 0):

Your getInfo() function returns array, so try to just print it like

```
echo '<pre>';
print_r($this->id);
echo '</pre>';
```

Comment: This will not be my solution because i want my "Id" and "Grad" to be stored in 2 sessions after echo.

Comment: then store it on $_SESSION global array

Comment: i would need to echo the Id and Grad on other page so it will not work.

Comment: Php runs on a per-request basis. To persist data across multiple page requests, you would need to store the data in the $_SESSION global array, or fetch it from the database on ever request.